# How to process the jobs in same runner and session in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, cicd, gitlab-ci.yml

I have a GitLab workflow. I have 5 stages which are 1: copy the project to server, 2: syntax check in the same server(same folder), 3: format test and rules test in the same server, 4: stress test (there are many case tests in different jobs in this stage), 5: deleting the project from server.

I can run all the things above in one job. However, I wanted to see the situations for each job separately on the GitLab page.

I am using artifacts already. So I can use the artifact to save the situation and show the job result as @Raghu suggested in the comments. However, it will slow down because every time a container starts up for only gives error or succes feedback by looking artifacts.

Is it possible to do it? or is there any other solution for this?

Comment: Each gitlab job executes in a separate container. But you could still transfer artifacts between jobs and thats the means of communication between them if one job needs to to hand off any data to another job. Add some more detail to your question on what exactly is your use case. It is not clear when you say "hey all communicate with another server". Please give a minimal code so that others can understand and will help in suggesting a solution

Comment: Ok I will update the question. sorry for lack of information.